# Website Root files in Azure and Databases in Amazon

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, azure, hosting

I hosted Web site on my Azure Account. And now the cost of File downloading is more and Amazon is cheaper than Azure. Can I use Sql Database which is hosted in Amazon in Azure website?

Comment: Im almost sure that yes you can , you need to add privileges to azure to connect with Amazon, firewall for example.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, but you probably shouldn't:

1. Securing a connection from an Azure VM / Web Role / Website to a SQL
   instance running in AWS would be pretty hard (source IP filters
   would probably not be a workable option and allowing anything IP to connect to your SQL Instance probably isn't a good idea).
2. Even if you so figure out a way to secure the connection, latency would probably mean your website would be relatively unresponsive.